# shuffle() function and SIMD code generation

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, simd, auto-vectorization

I've been thinking about ecatmur's `constexpr` [`swap()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936584/how-to-write-constexpr-swap-function-to-change-endianess-of-an-integer%20function) function and I believe it's a special case of a more generic `shuffle()` function:

```
template <std::size_t ...I, std::size_t ...J, typename T>
constexpr T shuffle(T const i, std::index_sequence<J...>) noexcept
{
  return ((std::uint8_t(i >> 8 * I) << 8 * J) | ...);
}
```

`I` are source indices and `J` are destination indices. There are many different ways to implement `shuffle()` (I'll spare you the details), but, in my experience, the implementations don't induce gcc and clang to generate SIMD code equally well, when invoking `shuffle()` in a loop. Hence my question. Does there exist a formulation of `shuffle()`, that clang and gcc like to SIMDify more than the existing one, maybe using built-in functions or intrinsics? I am not aiming at a specific instruction set.

Comment: Modern clang is somewhat good at auto-vectorizing shuffles, compared to other compilers.  At least with compile-time constant data-movement I think I've seen it succeed.

Comment: It's very good, I'm not disputing that, but gcc isn't :) They both auto-vectorize this horror and clang does a better job. I'm just trying to see, if there's an optimal solution for both compilers.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <std::size_t ...I, std::size_t ...J, typename T>
constexpr T shuffle(T const i, std::index_sequence<J...>) noexcept
{
  return ((T{0xff} << 8 * J) & (I < J ? i << 8 * (J - I) : i >> 8 * (I - J)) | ...);
}
```

We see that a constant is ANDed to the result of a single shift operation, the operands being independent of each other, making the expression better suited for vectorization.